# Add set of controls dynamically on Button Click c# wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a requirement to add a panel containing some user controls like textboxes, listviews with their own validations operating on these controls, on a button click. So every time a user clicks a button, a new panel would be generated with the above controls in the same window.

Any help, links, suggestions or pointers would be appreciated?

Comment: there are plenty examples/frameworks fufiling such requirement.

Comment: Im a beginner in C# wpf. So appreciate any links / snippets where i can get the understanding. thanks

Comment: [Data Binding Demo](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/microsoft/wpf-samples/data-binding-demo/)

Answer (score 0):

Hello I hope I understood you correctly, I have made a small sample.

XAML Codes:

```
<Window x:Class="My_First_WPF_App.TestWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"
    xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006"
    mc:Ignorable="d"
    Title="TestWindow" Height="450" Width="800">
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel x:Name="StackPanelTest"/>
    <StackPanel Margin="0,10,0,0" Orientation="Horizontal">
        <Button x:Name="AddItemsBTN" Content="Add Controls" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="50,0,0,0" VerticalAlignment="Top" Click="AddItemsBTN_Click"/>
        <Button x:Name="ClearItemsBTN" Margin="50,0,0,0" Content="Clear Controls" Click="ClearItemsBTN_Click"></Button>
    </StackPanel>
</StackPanel>
```

C# Codes:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;

namespace My_First_WPF_App
{
/// <summary>
/// Interaction logic for TestWindow.xaml
/// </summary>
public partial class TestWindow : Window
{
    public TestWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }


    private void ClearItemsBTN_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StackPanelTest.Children.Clear();
    }

    private void AddItemsBTN_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        StackPanel SP = new StackPanel();
        SP.Orientation = Orientation.Horizontal; SP.Margin = new Thickness(50, 20, 0, 0);
        TextBlock TestTextBlock = new TextBlock();
        TestTextBlock.Text = "Your Test ListView: ";
        ListView LV = new ListView();
        Button AddItemsBTN = new Button();
        AddItemsBTN.Content = "Add a new item: "; AddItemsBTN.Margin = new Thickness(20, 0, 0, 0);
        AddItemsBTN.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center; AddItemsBTN.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        TextBox AddTXTBox = new TextBox(); AddTXTBox.Margin = new Thickness(10, 0, 0, 0); AddTXTBox.MinWidth = 20;
        AddTXTBox.HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Center; AddTXTBox.VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Center;
        AddItemsBTN.Click += delegate
        {
            LV.Items.Add(AddTXTBox.Text);
            AddTXTBox.Text = "";
        };
        SP.Children.Add(TestTextBlock); SP.Children.Add(LV); SP.Children.Add(AddItemsBTN); SP.Children.Add(AddTXTBox);
        StackPanelTest.Children.Add(SP);
    }
}
```

}